# terminal auto complete doesnot work in adb command

Tags: command-line, auto-completion, adb

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (updated), in terminal, auto complete works well but when I'm using adb command in terminal, auto complete does not work anymore..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just perform the following simple steps:

1. Copy and paste the **adb bash completion** from [here on github](https://github.com/mbrubeck/android-completion/blob/master/android) by mbrubeck and save in a file named **adb.txt** or the name you prefer.
2. Store the file somewhere safe. Anywhere you want in your $PATH. I choose `/bin` but the standard file location is `/usr/local/bin`.
3. Use your favorite editor of choice (which should be vim IMHO) to edit your `~/.bashrc` file.
4. Add the following lines (substitute your own path to the adb bash completion file) to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file (**not edit the .bashrc in sudo mode**):

   ```
   if [ -e /bin/adb.txt ] ; then
     source /bin/adb.txt
   fi
   ```
5. Save and quit. To reload your bash type:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
6. Check if it works.  Type `adb d` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see if it autocompletes to `adb devices`.

Here you can find the full manual to [AutoComplete ADB](http://www.jessechen.net/blog/protip-bash-autocomplete-for-android-adb/).

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: @Fabby Answer got expanded.

Comment: Good one now!  Upvoted!  :-) **Tip:** use 8 spaces instead of 4 when using numbered lists.  Please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/617293/revisions) for further tips&tricks...  **;-)**  @ByteCommander: thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @Fabby thanks for the correction, next time I'll follow the tips

Comment: Thanks for reply..I tried this but still not working...:(

Comment: @Deniz which is the problem?  wrong output? no output?

Comment: my problem is when i want to install any application from terminal output of adb devices is ok but when i try to install like adb install /home... here autocomplete doesnot complete the path of my application

Comment: so the adb autocomplete works but now the path complete not work...
It is so strange, I have just try and works...let me try again

Comment: yes in path does not work.. and i have to type path completely

Comment: @Deniz I suggest you to redo the steps again.
I have follow the steps from fresh now and all works.
Maybe some typo during the copy and paste, some wrong path in the ~/.bashrc file?

Comment: in terminal path auto complete works but only in adb command doesnot work..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23455/discussion-between-ad3luc-and-deniz).

Comment: Perfect! :) happy to help

Answer (score 3):

1. Download this [script](https://github.com/mbrubeck/android-completion).
2. Install `bash-completion` if you haven't already by running:

   `sudo apt-get install bash-completion`
3. Copy the downloaded file from step 1 into the `/etc/bash_completion.d` folder
4. Restart your shell.